# Replacing a JButton in java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jradiobutton

I'm not sure how I can go about replacing a `JButton` with a `JRadioButton` when the `JButton` is clicked. So say if I had Jpanel set as a gridlayout which lays out 4 rows (3 JLabels and a JButton). So when the user clicks the `JButton`, that JButton will be replaced with a `JRadioButton`.

Would I use a `CardLayout` for this purpose, or is there a simple way in replacing that `JButton`?

Comment: not there isn't some issue with that, but have to add JComponents with numbering by holding its ZOrder, then to call revalidate and repaint to its container

Comment: *"Would I use a `CardLayout` for this purpose,"*  Sure,  it can go inside the `GridBagLayout`.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you could do is remove the button from the pannle and add a radio button in its place

Example code

```
  static JButton button1 = new JButton("Test");
  static JPanel panel1 = new JPanel():
  public static void main(String[] args{
  panel1.add(button1);
  }
  public void ActionListener(ActionEvent e){
  if(e.equals("Test"){
  panel1.remove(button1);
  panel1.add(radiobutton1);
  }
```

from here you can add your radieo button

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. So in my case I could add the radioButton at position 3 (4th row JButton) to the JPanel. I was thinking too much into it. Thanks again

Comment: This method is unnecessary and buggy.  Especially if the radio button is larger than the button.  Combined with poor formatting and forgetting to inform the GUI to update the layout, -1.  Tip to the OP - *Use a `CardLayout`.*

Comment: this code is only for getting an idea of how you can swape out buttons. i had no idea about cardlayouts when i wrote this. if you want to say my idea is bad and propse a tip, give some code so the guy asking the question and people reading this have an idea on how to do what you say